# dmesg gives error message "lo ate my IP adress" recently

Tags: linux, dmesg

Normally I use Kubuntu 20.04, but because of some problems I run since a long time KNOPPIX 9.1.

uname -a says:

Linux Microknoppix 5.10.10-64 #3 SMP PREEMPT Sun Feb 7 09:26:54 CET 2021 x86-64 GNU-Linux.

I use KDE.

I have updated most packages.

Info-Center shows:

KFE Plasma Version: 5.26.4

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.100.0

Qt Version: 5.15.6

Kernel Version: 5.10.10-64 (32-bit)

Graphics Platform: X11

I never use graphics, I have under Konsole about 15 windows with Terminal xterm-256color, with shell bash in each, bash version 5.2.15(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

dmesg I use weekly, but not in the last 2-3 weeks.

I have worked on a long shell script.

Now I had to use dmesg, but dmesg does not work any more.

As always I called

```
dmesg -s $((10 * 1024 * 1024)) -T | less
```

All lines contain the error message:

```
lo ate my IP address
```

In all my life such a message I never have read.

Googling results in some bug notes in the years 2006, 2008 regarding this error message.

I do not even understand the error message: what do the shurtcuts "lo" and "ate" mean?

Has "lo" something to do with verb look?

Is "ate" the past of verb eat, eating (german: essen)?

What may have corrupted dmesg.

aptitude does not show that dmesg, resp. util-linux can be updated.

```
apt-get install util-linux
```

results in exit code "0" and does nothing, no re-install.

Same with "muon".

Normally, even when the newest version is installed, I can cause a re-install.

Please, what can I do ?

Regards

== edited 19.01.2003 01:06

With muon I was able to re-install the thee packages relevant to util-linux, which were installed.

The new dmesh shows in all lines again the same error message, from line 1 of 17.01.2023 17:54:44 up to line 2047 of 19.02.2023 01:03:24.

Regards

== edited 19.01.2003 01:20

Remarkable: Consecutive calls of dmesg result always in 2047 lines of less-output.

That is not normal, Otherwise I have more lines, and the number of lines is increasing.

Regards

Comment: Sometimes I can delete the network profile, restart, and remake the network profile. That resets a number of network settings and may assist here.

Comment: `lo` is probably a reference to your loopback adapter. yes the word `ate` is the past tense of "to eat" as in to consume or to devour, which is in this case "to take" or "to make disappear". in this case it is likely that your other network interfaces do not have an IP address assigned, because of an issue coordinating the multiple interfaces/

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean with "network profile", and what do you mean with "restart", "do you mean "reboot"?, I cannot reboot, many would go lost, I have to copy to a new USB stick, but after every plug-in, I always got the device name of the new plugged-in by dmesg.  I am looking for another way to get reported the device name a new device had received. Regards

Comment: loopback adapter???: my network -- if "connect" I do enable -- is functioning since I can surfe and can download plus install. dmesg in the past I have used locally, without any regard to a nework. Regards

Comment: == 19.01.2023: I have found my old script which lists all plugged-in USB devices, based on /sys/...uevent. This I will begiin to use now. Regards

Comment: == 19.01.2023 20:50 : When I plug in a new USB stick my list of USB devices is not extended. This is also true for lsblk and other commands/utilities. Thus the problem is greater:: not only dmesg does not work, also new plugged-in USB sticks are not accepted by the kernel. I have checked: the letters for devices /dev/sd?: most are taken but v, w, x y are free. What could be the reason? Regards

Comment: == 20.01.2023 02:00 : some progress: I have disconnected /dev/sdt external 120 GB flash disk with partitions sdt1, sdt2, sdt5. -- dmesg is not totally broken. Now I can see between the many lines "lo ate my IP address" messages from my attempt at about 17:45 to plug in and make working the new USB stick, reporting: "No enough host controller resources for new device state.  can't set config #1, error -12" -- Now 20.01.2023 about 02:00 successfull plug-in of new USB stick, with same message but without error message -- yet still between ongoing lines "lo ate ...". I do not understand t events.

Comment: Meta note: the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1763685/revisions) exists, it keeps timestamps and there is no need to duplicate its functionality by injecting `edited 19.01.2003 01:20` or so to the body of the post. Not only such snippets are unnecessary, they may be misleading because timezones exist. Similarly each comment has its timestamp (it may be displayed as "9 hours ago" or "yesterday"; but when you hover the cursor over this text, the accurate timestamp should appear).

Comment: == 21.01.2023 09:53 to Meta Note of Kamil Marciorowsi :: thank you, but on my Samsung, Galaxy S10+ it is not so. I cannot hover a cursor, I can only hit the text with my finger. And by this a usable time is not shown. All my comments have the same timestamp "yesterday", and your note has "21 hours ago". This is a very bad habit. All date/time writings have to be in the same full time format, best as e.g. "--time-style=iso-long". Regards

Comment: == 21.01.2023 10:30 :: continuation of my 20.01.2023 02:00 :: after the progress I described, the new USB stick, after pug-in got the device name /dev/sdt1 and is usable.  Yet problems remain. 1. dmesg continues to give automatically  the error message lines "lo ate ...". These are given in clusters. Each cluster consists of 4 to 6 lines with equal time, even seconds are same. And the clusters come in intervals of 15 sec.  2. The total number of lines given by dmesg is currently always 1998, and does now grow. 3. (continued in next comment). Regards

Comment: == 21.01.2023 10:37 :: continuation of my 21

Comment: == 21.01.2023 10:37 :: continuation of my 21.01.2023 10:30 :: remaining problem 3. Without any warning when firsttime the cause event happend, the error message was: "Not enough host controller recources for new device state. can't set config #1 error -21". What is this, why is this. -- Is there a linux measure for this, or have I to develop an onwn watch dog, how to? Regards